# Existence of a group morphism between an arbitrary group and an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying a course in abstract algebra. Recently I solved an exercise which said that if you had a group $G$, its commutator $[G:G]$,  an abelian group $K$ and a group morphism $f:G \rightarrow K$ then you can factorize this group morphism uniquely by the quotient $G/[G:G]$. For this I used the universal property of quotient group.

My doubt is whether you can guarantee the existence of this morphism given any (say) finite group. I know that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ where $n$ is the order of the group. What I'm asking is a little bit more specific. I checked Hungerford's and Artin's books and couldn't find an answer. Maybe I should check a book on group theory? Thanks!

Comment: There are no nontrivial homomorphisms from a finite simple group into an abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should also check that $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, itself.

Then, what do you mean "guarantee the existence of this morphism..."? If $G/[G,G]$ is not isomorphic to any non-trivial subgroup of abelian group $K$, then the only group hom $G\to K$ is the map to $\{e_K\}$. Yes, this does factor through $G/[G,G]$.

But, yes, *any* group hom $G\to K$ for abelian $K$ does factor *uniquely* through the quotient $G/[G,G]$. Existence of the $G\to K$ assures the existence of the associated map $G/[G,G]\to K$, if that's what you're asking.

EDIT: to incorporate @DanielSchepler's comment (since comments can and will get deleted at some point): yes, in particular, since $G/[G,G]$ is always abelian, if it is non-trivial then the quotient map $G\to G/[G,G]$ is a non-trivial hom to an abelian group... Is this the issue?

And, indeed, for simple $G$, $[G,G]=G$... since any hom $G\to H$ has a kernel, which is normal, which can only be $G$ or $\{e\}$.

Comment: Sorry, clearly I didn't phrase my question correctly. I have already proved that $G/[G:G]$ is abelian. My question is given a finite group $G$ can you construct a morphism to an abelian group, preferrently not the identity? Someone said on the comments that if the group is finite simple you can't do it. The question came to me as I was trying to make an explicit example of this proposition. Hopes that clears it up.

Comment: and thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LeoLerena If $G^{\mathrm{ab}} := G / [G : G]$ is a nontrivial group, then the quotient map $G \to G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is a nontrivial morphism to an abelian group.  If $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is trivial, then by the lemma, any homomorphism from $G$ to an abelian group must be the identity.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I couldn't quite connect the dots! Thanks very much, now I understand what Paul meant. I will probably accept the answer!

Comment: Yes! That was the issue, now it's clear! Well explained, thanks.